# Smooth hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ containing a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$(over complex numbers), then we know that $X$ contains a line.

Then my question is : Is the same thing true for smooth hypersurfaces of degree $\geq 5$?In particular what happens for quintic hypersurface?

My guess is that it should not necessarily contain a line. But I don't have a concrete counterexample.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: A few questions: why did you skip from degree 4 to degree 5? How much have you thought about this - is this just an idle curiosity, or have you made your own attempts at solving the problem?

Comment: Hint: compute the dimension of the variety of pairs $(X,L)$ where $L \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a line and $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a degree $d$ hypersurface such that $L \subset X$.

Comment: @KReiser, My original problem was to find out the maximum number of collinear points on a curve $C \subset \mathbb P^3$ which is smooth and irreducible and given by complete intersection of a very general surface of degree $d \geq 4$ and a smooth hypersurface of degree $d \geq 3$. Now if the second surface is degree $3$ then it contains a line and by Bezout argument we are done. This motivated me to ask the above question.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks. For $d >3$ not all smooth surfaces contain a line. But Is there a way around to calculate the maximum number of collinear points of such $C$ mentioned in my previous comment?